# Postgres send output of COPY over the network

Tags: postgresql

I would like to do the following:

`psql -c "COPY (SELECT a.id, b.id FROM a JOIN b USING id) TO STDOUT;"`

the problem is that it would never send anything until the join is fully computed. Is there a way to tell Postgres to output the join while its being computed without writing it into a some temporary storage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `psql`'s `\copy`.

```
\COPY (SELECT a.id, b.id FROM a JOIN b USING id) TO stdout;
```

You can replace `stdout` with `'/path/to/file'` if desired.

An inner join can be incrementally computed, so there should be no issues there presuming the tables aren't views over more complex queries. Show the output of `explain select ...` if you still don't get incremental output.

Comment: thanks, that seems to do the job. my join is slightly more complex than `a JOIN B`

Comment: Actually, from the docs of `psql:    \copy { table [ ( column_list ) ] | ( query ) } { from | to } { 'filename' | program 'command' | stdin | stdout | pstdin | pstdout } [ [ with ] ( option [, ...] ) ]
           Performs a frontend (client) copy. This is an operation that runs an SQL COPY(7) command, but instead of the server reading or writing the specified file, psql
           reads or writes the file and routes the data between the server and the local file system.` So its same as `COPY TO .. STDOUT` with respect to `JOIN` computation